# Find file with at least one number in /usr/include

Tags: regex, bash, find, slash

Using the `find` command, I want to see the files in `/usr/include` whose name contains `at least one number`.

I tried this command :

```
find /usr/include -type f -regex '.\*[0-9].\*$'
```

But the number is not always in the name of the file but sometimes in the path. For example `/usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ah.h` is found.

After that, I tried this command :

```
find /usr/include -type f -regex '/[^\/]*[0-9][^\/]*$'
```

But it returns nothing.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the `-name` test instead of the `-regex` test, it will match only the filename, ignoring the preceding directories ([see the man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)). Note that `-name` uses a shell pattern rather than a regex pattern, so the syntax is slightly different. You can use this command to find files which have numbers in the filename:

```
find /usr/include -type f -name '*[0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 1):

With regex itself:

```
find /usr/include/ -type f -regex ".*/[^/]*[0-9][^/]*"
```

Here, we look for atleast 1 number after the last `/` in the file names.